# Display all WooCommerce products made by a user using a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to get all products of an user, and I get more products than I have in DB (`wp_posts`) for that user .

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'post_author' =>  296,
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
```

Update:

- from my debug I find that all my users have 0 products, except post_author 1 (admin), this is strange because in wp_posts on post_author I have more IDs, and user 1 has just a few.

Comment: It's not `post_author` it is just `author` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters

Comment: I also used "author", but in this case I get no product.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$products = wc_get_products( array(
    'status'    => 'publish',
    'limit'     => -1,
    'author'    => 296 //author ID
) );
```

Comment: I get an empty array.

Comment: Yes, in database it has 2 products that are publish and more as a draft.